# Use where clause in count function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to create a table with 2 columns. 1 column contains the amount paid each month while the other column contains the number of customer who ordered that month and paid that month.

```
select sum(paid), count(distinct customer where Order_Month = Paid_Month)
from DataTable
group by Paid_Month
```

Is there an easy way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select sum(paid),
       count(distinct case when Order_Month = Paid_Month then customer end)
from DataTable
group by Paid_Month;
```